# rails externaldb or many-to-many model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say there is already an existing database,

```
{
cartype,owner,fromdate,todate
car1, xxx, xxx, xxx
car1, xxx, xxx, xxx
car2, xxx, xxx, xxx
car2, xxx, xxx, xxx
car2, xxx, xxx, xxx
car3, xxx, xxx, xxx
car3, xxx, xxx, xxx
}
```

Based on the first field, we can get the history of that particular car.

Now, let's assume we are gathering users interested in those cars.

So, we have 2 tables: "User" table which has userid as column. And a user can be interested in multiple cars. So we have another table "Usercars" table which will have something like:

```
user1, car1
user1, car2,
user1, car3,
user2, car2
user2, car3
```

Now if want to model this in rails, I am thinking the easiest would be to just model the user table with a 1-to-many relationship with usercars table and keep the car history in a completely separate database. So for a particular user, if we want to display the history of all the cars he is interested in, we do a "select * from externaldb where car=car1|car2|car3 "(an equivalent of that) and send out the information.

I would like to know your thoughts on this. Is this an acceptable way or should I somehow make car history also part of the model, coz the way I see it, it is something we are not controlling(for example I get that data from an api).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a third table for cars yes. Something along these lines

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :user_cars
   has_many :users, through: :user_cars
end

class UserCar < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   belongs_to :car
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :user_cars
   has_many :cars, through: :user_cars
end
```

And you'll access your cars for a user by doing something like the following:

```
user = User.find_by_name("John")
user.cars
```

Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: I was thinking along similar lines, but then I thought that my application would only ever read(and not write) from the carhistory db, so does it really make sense to make it part of the model?

Comment: I'd say yes. You can flush the ```cars``` table after/before each load if needed. Using an Object Oriented (OO) approach makes a lot of thing way easier to manipulate. Rails is built to make the best of the OO approach, you can use all rails power by doing it that way. So create instance of the Car object with the result of your other DB request, and you're good to go!